# how to match entries and display entries

Tags: java, arrays

**I do not know how to display entries entered by user, and also to match and sort them.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Case1

{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Input a size of an array: ");
    int size = in.nextInt();
    int num[]=new int[size];
    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Input a number: ");
        num[i]=in.nextInt();
    }

    for (int c=0;i<num.length;c++){
        for (int a=0; a<num.length;a++){
            if(num[c]>num[a]){
                int temp = num[c];
                num[c]= num[a];
                num[a]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int d=0;i<num.length;d++){
        int value = 0;
        if(value==num[i])   {
            System.out.println("Match Found!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

help please.

Comment: In your last for loop you are increasing the value of 'd' while 'i' remains the same. I think you want to change `i<num.length` to 'd<num.length` and also change `if(value==num[i])` to `if(value==num[d])`. Just noticed you also have the same problem in your second for loop when dealing with `c` you still check if `i` is less than `num.length`

Comment: I mean how can I display the entries in sort form.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this ->

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Case1

{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Input a size of an array: ");
    int size = in.nextInt();
    int num[]=new int[size];
    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Input a number: ");
        num[i]=in.nextInt();
    }

    // DISPLAY ENTRIES
    System.out.println("You entered the following entries.");
    for (int index=0; index<num.length; index++) {
        System.out.print(index + ": " + num[index] + " ");
    }
    // END DISPLAY ENTRIES

    for (int c=0;c<num.length;c++){ // Changed i to c
        for (int a=0; a<num.length;a++){
            if(num[c]>num[a]){
                int temp = num[c];
                num[c]= num[a];
                num[a]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int d=0;d<num.length;d++){ // Changed i to d
        int value = 0;
        if(value==num[d])   { // Changed i to d
            System.out.println("Match Found!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

This should work, but when you asked in your question about matching, did you want to match each entry with 0 (which makes no sense) or did you want to compare each entry to 0?

Comment: I already did this, thanks for that. I have one more problem. I don't know how to display the entries. for example, the user input a size of an array, then input a number, then the next should be, --display the input values in general output.(my problem now)

Comment: Edited the answer to include an example of displaying the entries

Comment: i got an error, 

"cant find symbol variable index" from line 21 and line 22

Comment: fixed it, forgot to declare `index` as `int`

Comment: Alright if we were to run through my code it would do the following:"Input a size of an array:" 1(We input 1, which creates an array of size one, but all arrays start at index 0, next) Input a number: 10(We input 10, storing 10 into num[0]) You entered the following entries. 0: 10" the final output is structured as (index: entry) for how ever many entries there are. So if you had ten entries and they were all 100, the first output would be (0: 100) and the last output would be (9: 100). Also I edited my code one more time to fix a spacing issue with multiple entries.